# Download Package in Package Designer does not work

Tags: azure, package-designer

When I try to **download generated package** into Sitecore Package designer, nothing is happened. Just only a**n error**, that I can observe in Chrome Dev Tool (**sitecore.js**, line 1058):

[image]

In additional, the generated package does really exists and is located on CM server into '**packages**' folder.

**Details:**

- Azure VM
- Sitecore 8.2
- CM Server
- Packages folder is located on Azure VM 'Temporary Storage'
- Cisco VPN

Comment: I would take this with Sitecore Support. Seems that URI is not generated correctly to align with Azure VM temporary storage location or something

Comment: @PeterProcházka, probably that makes sense. Also will forward this issue to Sitecore Support. Thank you!

Comment: When you get your answer from Support, please be so kind as to post an answer with the solution (i.e. details of bug ticket number and recommended solution).

Comment: Unfortunately, was not able to logging into [Sitecore Support](https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/login). Messaged to Sitecore. Thus, I am waiting for an answer. Let's see.